# Configuring Catalogs to connect to multiple clusters requires setting a single connection host

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to connect to multiple Cassandra Cluster to enable running a data migration, although I couldn't find any documentation about how this could be accomplished.

Last thing I tried was to follow the catalogs option (https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/1_connecting.md), although it keeps forcing me to set a single connection host.

Is there any way around that?

Here's some examples of what I tried:

```
./start-thriftserver.sh \
    --master spark://master:7077 \
    --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port=10000 \
    --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.bind.host=here \
    --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.3.0 \
    --conf spark.sql.extensions=com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraSparkExtensions \
    --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host:db1=db1 \
    --conf spark.cassandra.auth.username:db1=user1 \
    --conf spark.cassandra.auth.password:db1=pass1 \
    --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host:db2=db2 \
    --conf spark.cassandra.auth.username:db2=user2 \
    --conf spark.cassandra.auth.password:db2=pass2
```

I tried other notations as well, like db1/spark.cassandra... no luck.

Also tried using catalogs:

```
./start-thriftserver.sh \
--master spark://master:7077 \
--hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port=10000 \
--hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.bind.host=here \
--packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.3.0 \
--conf spark.sql.extensions=com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraSparkExtensions \
--conf spark.sql.catalog.db1=com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.CassandraCatalog \
--conf spark.sql.catalog.db1.spark.cassandra.connection.host=db1 \
--conf spark.sql.catalog.db1.spark.cassandra.auth.username=user1 \
--conf spark.sql.catalog.db1.spark.cassandra.auth.password=pass1 \
--conf spark.sql.catalog.db2=com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.CassandraCatalog \
--conf spark.sql.catalog.db2.spark.cassandra.connection.host=db2 \
--conf spark.sql.catalog.db2.spark.cassandra.auth.username=user2 \
--conf spark.sql.catalog.db2.spark.cassandra.auth.password=pass2
```

Although it keeps trying to access Cassandra at localhost too.

I wonder if the only option I will have is to create some code to setup SparkConf objects manually.

Comment: Please add a few more details so we can help you. In particular, please provide (1) a minimal sample code that replicates the problem, and (2) the full error message + full stack trace. Cheers!

Comment: @ErickRamirez Thank you. I've added some of the attempts I've been making. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Cassandra are you using?